# Why does the katakana ラ look similar to the hiragana う?

Tags: katakana, hiragana

More specifically, is there a historical reason why some katakana characters look similar to the hiragana ones, as the question suggests?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80013/discussion-on-question-by-razorsyntax-why-does-the-katakana--look-similar-to-th).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is just a coincidence.  As you (probably) know, both hiragana and katakana came into existence as shorthand for kanji.  Here's the graph shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana).  So you can see that ラ and う are derived from different kanji and just so happen to look similar.

[image: kana]

Comment: Actually, I didn't know it was shorthand.  That's awesome!

Comment: To expand on this note, Japanese had no written form until the Chinese writing system was adopted via Korea, and writing was done by translating the Japanese into classical Chinese; this was until the use of Man'yougana, which was a syllabary consisting of kanji used to represent associated sounds (often more than one kanji per sound); this led to hiragana, whose shapes were based on the *overall* shape of a particular kanji, and katakana, whose shapes were based on the shape of a *component* of the same kanji.

Comment: There is also the issue of [Joudai Tokushu Kanazukai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Ddai_Tokushu_Kanazukai), distinctions between two classes of manyougana that distinguished a number of sounds, but the distinction was lost when manyougana stopped being used in favor of kana, which did not differentiate between the two classes of sound.